# Prove or disprove that $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} P(T\geq u, U \geq t) =\frac{\partial}{\partial u} P(T \geq u, U \geq T)$ at $u=t$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $U$ and $T$ be two non-negative random variables, $T$ has density. Prove or disprove this: $$\bigg (\frac{\partial}{\partial u} P(T\geq u, U \geq t) \bigg )_{u=t}= \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial u} P(T \geq u, U \geq T)\bigg )_{u=t}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: Assume that $U=t$ almost surely, then
$$
P(T\geqslant u,U\geqslant t)=P(T\geqslant u),
$$
whose derivative at $u=t$ is $-f_T(t)$, while
$$
P(T\geqslant u,U\geqslant T)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}0&\text{if}&u\gt t,\\P(u\leqslant T\leqslant t)&\text{if}&u\leqslant t,\end{array}\right.
$$
whose one-sided derivatives at $u=t$ are $-f_T(t)$ from the left and $0$ from the right.